# Get index when looping through one column of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe:

index, a, y
0    , 1, 2
1    , 4, 6
2    , 5, 8

I want to loop through the "a" column, and print out its index for a specific value.

```
for x in df.a:
    if x == 4:
        print ("Index of that row")
```

What syntax should I use to obtain the index value when the for loop hits the specific value in the "a" column that I am seeking?

Thank You

Comment: Though you can loop through dataframes, I don't believe it is as efficient as using logicals.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
df[df.a==4].index.values
```

to get an array of those indices

Comment: This will work better as the model gets bigger. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

A series is like a dictionary, so you can use the `.iteritems` method:

```
for idx, x in df['a'].iteritems():
    if x==4:
        print('Index of that row: {}'.format(idx))
```

Comment: Great answer. But this answer more suites to be for a question which is how to loop through a dataframe column in the fastest possible way