# Trying to pull individual values from a dataframe but pulls arrays instead

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has a list of companies and a date in which a subscription service ends for each company like so:

```
 Service           Date
Company 1       02-09-2021
Company 2       03-11-2021
Company 3       05-13-2021
```

My code is here:

```
plants = []
for i in range(0,14):
    if i <=7:
        dates.append(today+timedelta(days=i))
        dates[i] = dates[i].strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
        plt = df[df.tService < dates[i]].Plant.values
        plants.append(df[df.tService < dates[i]].Plant.values)

for plant in plants:
    print(plant)
```

This dataframe has about 45 entries and what I wanted to do was find the ones that were expiring soon and get notified for it. I am trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41070549/get-index-when-looping-through-one-column-of-pandas) to get it to print the date column then compare it to a specific date (like, two weeks from now) but the issue I am running in to is that I get the each entry into my list as an array as below and I thought maybe running through it in a for loop would solve that issue but it doesn't. I understand how this is happening so my question is is there something I can do to get values from a dataframe not in a list format? I've tried taking the list it spits out below and removing any duplicates and it gives the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` so I also can't get rid of duplicates. Any idea on what I can do here to get the dates below the date I select (so anything that will show up in the next two weeks) in a format that I can print? Because each time I try to print it just prints as `['Wagon Trail' '603Brewery' 'East Brother Beer']` because that is considered one entry.

```
['Wagon Trail' '603Brewery' 'East Brother Beer']
['Wagon Trail' '603Brewery' 'East Brother Beer']
['Wagon Trail' '603Brewery' 'East Brother Beer']
['Wagon Trail' '603Brewery' 'East Brother Beer']
['Wagon Trail' '603Brewery' 'East Brother Beer']
['Wagon Trail' '603Brewery' 'East Brother Beer']
['Wagon Trail' '603Brewery' 'East Brother Beer']
['Wagon Trail' '603Brewery' 'East Brother Beer']
['Wagon Trail' '603Brewery' 'East Brother Beer']
```

Comment: Can you just filter your dataFrame when the date minus 14 days is equal to today?

Comment: @It_is_Chris The issue would be then, I wouldn't know when those expiration dates are. So I would get notified for something and then have to go and check the date which would defeat the purpose? Or maybe I am misunderstanding what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'Service': [f'Company {x}' for x in range(1, 32)],
                  'Date': pd.date_range('2021-04-10', '2021-05-10')})

# filter your frame where the date minus 14 days is equal to today
new = df[(df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta(days=14)) == pd.Timestamp.now().floor('d')]

       Service       Date
24  Company 25 2021-05-04
```

or you can do something like

```
# look for dates that are between today and today plus 14 days
new2 = df[df['Date'].between(pd.Timestamp.now().floor('d'),
                             pd.Timestamp.now().floor('d')+pd.Timedelta(days=14))]

       Service       Date
10  Company 11 2021-04-20
11  Company 12 2021-04-21
12  Company 13 2021-04-22
13  Company 14 2021-04-23
14  Company 15 2021-04-24
15  Company 16 2021-04-25
16  Company 17 2021-04-26
17  Company 18 2021-04-27
18  Company 19 2021-04-28
19  Company 20 2021-04-29
20  Company 21 2021-04-30
21  Company 22 2021-05-01
22  Company 23 2021-05-02
23  Company 24 2021-05-03
24  Company 25 2021-05-04
```

Comment: Sorry this took so long to accept as the answer, I was getting an empty dateframe so I thought it was busted but it turns out I didn't have any dates within the next 14 days, so I extended the timeframe and it works just fine. Now I just gotta figure out a way to make the printing a little more reader friendly for an email and I am good to go.